# Query to find the count of total IDs, and IDs having null in any column and the percentage of the two (i.e. Count of ID having null /total ID count)

Tags: sql, oracle, count, average

There are two tables.
Tables A has following structure

| ID | Flag | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1X | 1 | Y |
| 2Y | 0 | Null |
| 3Z | 1 | Null |
| 4A | 1 | Y |

Table B has the following structure

| B_ID | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1X | Y | Null |
| 2Y | Null | Null |
| 3Z | Null | Y |
| 4A | Y | Y |

I want to get the count of all the IDs and the count of IDs that have Null in any of the columns (name, city, state), for e.g from the tables above only the ID 4A has non null value in all the three columns across both the tables, so the output should be like

| Total_Count | Ids having null | Percentage missing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 0.75% |

Total_count is 4 as there are total of four IDs, ID having NULL is 3 because there are 3 IDs that have null in any of the three columns (viz. name,city,state), and Percentage missing is just IDs having null / Total_Count.

I tried using a query along the following lines

```
select (count/total) * 100 pct, count,total 
from (select sum(count) count 
      from(select count(*) count from tableA T1
      where T1.name is null
      union all
      select count(*) count from tableA T1
      join tableB T2 on T1.ID = T2.B_ID 
      where T2.city is null
      union all
      select count(*) count from tableA T1
      join tableB T2 on T1.ID = T2.B_ID 
      where T2.state is null)),
select count(ID) total from tableA);
```

But the query is not returning the desired output, can you please suggest me a better way?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total_Count,    
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Name IS NULL OR t2.City IS NULL OR t2.State IS NULL THEN 1 END) Ids_having_null,  
       AVG(CASE WHEN COALESCE(t1.Name, t2.City, t2.State) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Percentage_missing
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.B_ID = t1.ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f6be3f53273fb0ac9b7a0e1adf0f6a0f).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, much appreciated! @forpas

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know if either table has all the ID's?
Then I suggest a `full join` with some conditional aggregation in a sub-query.

**For example:**

> ```
> select 
>   Total as "Total_Count"  
> , TotalMissing as "Ids having null" 
> , (TotalMissing / Total)*100||'%' as "Percentage missing" 
> from
> (
>     select 
>       count(distinct coalesce(a.ID, b.B_ID)) as Total
>     , count(distinct case
>                      when a.name is null
>                        or b.city is null
>                        or b.state is null
>                       then coalesce(a.ID, b.B_ID) 
>                      end) as TotalMissing
>     from TableA a
>     full outer join TableB b 
>       on a.ID = b.B_ID
> ) q
> ```
>
> ```
> Total_Count | Ids having null | Percentage missing
> ----------: | --------------: | :-----------------
>           4 |               3 | 75%
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc025d2492d45cedc0e6d638ed7257f5)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this ->

```
select total_count, (total_count - cn) as ids_having_null, 
(total_count - cn) *100 / total_count as Percentage_missing 
FROM
(select count(t1.ID) as cn , t1.total_count 
 FROM ( select ID,Name, sum(tmp_col) over ( order by tmp_col) as total_count from  (select ID,Name, 1 as tmp_col  from tableA ) ) t1
 JOIN TableB t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.B_ID
 WHERE t1.Name is not null and t2.City is not null and t2.State is not null );
```

Based on your requirement for percentage or ratio, you can alter the logic for Percentage_missing column